# how to link one visualforce page from another visualforce page?

Tags: apex-code

I want to add two numbers that are given in a vf page text boxes. I want to print the result in another vf page by clicking the button (add button) in first page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by routing to the next page in Visualforce and passing the value you want to display as a parameter. Something like this in Apex should work:

```
PageReference gotoPage()
{
   PageReference pr = Page.YourSecondVFPage;
   pr.getParameters().put('secondnumber', '' + this.secondNumber);
   pr.setRedirect(true);
   return pr;
}
```

Then in Visualforce:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Go!" action="{!gotoPage}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try using the same controller on both pages. That way you don't have to pass all that data, assuming you have more than just a couple of fields to maintain, as url parameters or have to store the data somewhere if you don't have to.

If both pages are using the same controller and when you redirect the user using a PageReference make sure to set the redirect value to **false**, otherwise Salesforce treats as a new request and starts the page with a new instance of the controller.

The sample code below lets the user type some text into a field and then when print view is clicked it renders a PDF using that same information. No data was saved to database.

Controller

```
public with sharing class MyController {

public string MyData {get;set;}

public MyController() {
    MyData = '';    
}

public PageReference printView() {
    PageReference oPageRef = Page.MyPage2;
    oPageRef.setRedirect(false);

    return oPageRef;
}
}
```

Page 1:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
<apex:sectionheader title="Test" subtitle="My Page"/>

<apex:form id="formData">
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Data">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Printable View" action="{!printView}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="My Data"/>
                <apex:inputTextArea value="{!MyData}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Page 2:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController"
renderAs="pdf">

{!MyData}
</apex:page>
```